# Mybatis: Insert dynamic columns/values with Hashmap and retrieving generated key

Tags: mybatis

I have multiple tables where I need to insert new rows. I managed to insert the row using a HashMap.

This is the XML:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="de.gwvs.btix.database.model.GenericRecordMap">
    INSERT INTO ${genericRecordMap.tableName}
    <foreach open="(" close=")" collection="genericRecordMap.tableMap" index="col" separator=",">
      <trim>${col}</trim>
    </foreach>
    VALUES
    <foreach open="(" close=")" collection="genericRecordMap.tableMap" item="val" separator=",">
      <trim>#{val}</trim>
    </foreach>
  </insert>
```

This is my GenericRecordMap:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class GenericRecordMap {

  private String tableName;
  private Map<String, Object> tableMap;
  private long id;
  private String pk;
}
```

Does anybody know how to get the autogenerated key from that insert? I spent the whole day - unfortunatelly
no luck.

I tried the following definition:

```
  <insert id="insert" parameterType="de.gwvs.btix.database.model.GenericRecordMap" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="...">
```

`keyColumn="..."` is the problem. The column for the primary key varies depending on the table. I can substitute the
tablename by using `${genericRecordMap.tableName}` in the INSERT statement. But I did not manage to do
the same with the keyColumn. I tried `${pk}` no success. `${genericRecordMap.pk}` also did not work.

Without the `keyColumn` I get an SQLException from the OracleDB.

Has anybody an idea?

Best regards
Goran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "one-statement-for-all" strategy might seem like a good idea, but it usually isn't.
If you just want to avoid writing SQLs, check out [MyBatis Generator](https://mybatis.org/generator/).

Anyway, there is a workaround.
By using the `RETURNING ... INTO` clause and `CallableStatement`'s OUT parameter, you should be able to put the generated key to the `id` property.

```xml
<insert id="insert" statementType="CALLABLE">
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ${genericRecordMap.tableName}
    <foreach open="(" close=")" index="col" separator=","
      collection="genericRecordMap.tableMap">
      <trim>${col}</trim>
    </foreach>
    VALUES
    <foreach open="(" close=")" item="val" separator=","
      collection="genericRecordMap.tableMap">
      <trim>#{val}</trim>
    </foreach>
    RETURNING ${genericRecordMap.pk}
      INTO #{genericRecordMap.id,mode=OUT,jdbcType=BIGINT};
  END;
</insert>
```

Here is an executable demo.
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-76073846

Comment: Hi ave,
Thanks a lot for this workaround! 
I know, this kind of insert is not the "nicest" one and not recommended, but the users want to configure the different types of tables/columns by themselves. 
This is part of an XML-Import. The XML-Tags and XML-Attributes are mapped to different tables and columns. They don't like to wait for adjustments when new tags or attributes are sent within the XML file. With this solution they can configure their mappings by themselves and they are happy. 
So happy user - happy life :-)
Thanks again  and best regards.
Goran

Comment: You're very welcome. :) There sure are applications that prioritize flexibility over other stuff and this trick is useful when you work on them.